# SQL: How to select dates in a range by occurance

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data I have:

```html
   USERNAME |  DATE
   ---------------------
   USER1   |   7-1-2016
   USER1   |   7-5-2016
   USER1   |   7-8-2016
   USER2   |   7-2-2016
   USER2   |   7-5-2016
   USER2   |   7-6-2016
```

I need to select DISCINCT and return something like this:

```html
USER1,7-1-2016,NULL,NULL,NULL,7-5-2016,NULL,NULL,7-8-2016
USER2,NULL,7-2-2016,NULL,NULL,7-5-2016,7-6-2016,NULL,NULL
```

So, to help understand the need for a query like this.
I'd like to output a list of any given week in a more "calendar like" format, where the data is stored in a more linear (one line per date) format.

Thank You.

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question*). Please also include a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I added a dynamic way to do this, since i suspect you 'll have more than 8 dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `table pivoting`.  Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select username,
       max(case when date = '7-1-2016' then date end),
       max(case when date = '7-2-2016' then date end),
       max(case when date = '7-3-2016' then date end),
       max(case when date = '7-4-2016' then date end),
       max(case when date = '7-5-2016' then date end),
       max(case when date = '7-6-2016' then date end),
       max(case when date = '7-7-2016' then date end),
       max(case when date = '7-8-2016' then date end)
from yourtable
group by username
```

Comment: AWESOME.  This is interesting.  
Is there a way to expand this by adding some attributes?
Like:  max(case when date = '7-1-2016' then date as [Day1], additionalInfo as [DayID] end)

Comment: @stevo22 -- no you cannot add multiple columns in a single case statement -- you'd need to use multiple case statements instead (and include the alias after `end` for each).

Comment: Great.  This is much easier than I expected.   Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Before you pivot, you are going to need a table of dates since you want to include NULL, if you aren't going to do this with a bunch of conditional case statements. I.E. if you have a BUNCH of dates. I suggest populating a `CTE` and Joining to it first before you `PIVOT`. Then you will use dynamic SQL

```
--Staging table
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#HoldingTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #HoldingTable


--This is the date range you care about. You can set it to the MAX / MIN of your table if you want

DECLARE @DateFrom DATE
SET @DateFrom = '2016-07-01'

DECLARE @DateTo DATE
SET @DateTo = '2016-07-10'

;WITH DateRanges AS
(
    SELECT @DateFrom AS 'DateValue'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, DateValue)
    FROM DateRanges
    WHERE DateValue < @DateTo
),


--This is just me populating your test data
Data as(
SELECT 'USER1' AS USERNAME, '7/1/2016' AS DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'USER1' AS USERNAME, '7/5/2016' AS DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'USER1' AS USERNAME, '7/8/2016' AS DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'USER2' AS USERNAME, '7/2/2016' AS DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'USER2' AS USERNAME, '7/5/2016' AS DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'USER2' AS USERNAME, '7/6/2016' AS DATE
)


--Bring everything together for the dynamic SQL
SELECT * 
INTO #HoldingTable
FROM DateRanges dt
LEFT JOIN Data d on d.DATE = dt.DateValue
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)

--You'll see your data in vertical form here... we are about to pivot this
SELECT * FROM #HoldingTable

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


--Here is your dynamic pivot based off your date range

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(DateValue)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DateValue FROM #HoldingTable) AS DateValue

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT USERNAME, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #HoldingTable
    PIVOT(MAX(Date) 
          FOR DateValue IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable WHERE USERNAME IS NOT NULL'


--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot your table like this(where `[yourTable]` is your original data table):

```
SELECT [USERNAME], 
[7/1/2016], [7/2/2016], [7/3/2016], [7/4/2016], [7/5/2016],[7/6/2016],[7/7/2016],[7/8/2016]
FROM [yourTable] AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX([DATE])
FOR [DATE] IN ([7/1/2016], [7/2/2016], [7/3/2016], [7/4/2016], [7/5/2016],[7/6/2016],[7/7/2016],[7/8/2016])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use STUFF with XML as following:

```
 declare @calendar table(dates datetime)
 declare @i tinyint = 1
    while (@i<=8)
    begin 
        insert into @calendar
        select '7-'+cast(@i as char(1))+'-2016'
        set @i=@i+1
    end

   declare @test table (userid varchar(10), userDate datetime)
   insert into @test 
   select 'user1','7-1-2016'
   union
   select 'user1','7-5-2016'
   union 
   select 'user1','7-8-2016'
   union
   select 'user2','7-2-2016'
   union
   select 'user2','7-5-2016'
   union
   select 'user2','7-6-2016'

   ; with CTE as (
   select d.userid,dates,userDate
   from (select * from @calendar c cross apply (select distinct userid from @test) u) d
   left join @test t
   on d.dates=t.userDate
   and d.userid=t.userid
   --order by d.userid,t.userdate,d.dates
   )
    SELECT userId,
    STUFF((
    SELECT ','+
        case when userDate is null then 'null' else convert(varchar(20),userDate,101) end 
        AS [text()]
    FROM CTE CC
    WHERE CC.userid=C.userid
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Dates
    FROM (
    select distinct userId
    FROM CTE 
    ) C
```